"FieldValue.arrayUnion is not a function" error
I have tried lot to fix the "FieldValue.arrayUnion is not a function" error by updating my npm version several times, but its not working. I am getting an error at the arrayUnion line. Please help me to fix the issue.
CODE:
try {
    const recipientDocRef = doc(db, 'usersNew', selectedFriend.username);

    await updateDoc(recipientDocRef, {
        friendRequests: FieldValue.arrayUnion(user.uid)
    });

    toast.success(`Friend request sent to ${selectedFriend.username}`);
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending friend request:', error);

    // More specific error messages (if possible)
    if (error.code === 'firestore/permission-denied') {} else {
        toast.error('You do not have permission to send friend requests. Please check your Firestore rules.');
    }
    toast.error('Error sending friend request. Please try again.');
} finally {
    setIsLoadingRequest(false);
}

This is how I import FieldValue:
import { FieldValue } from 'firebase/firestore'; 

I tried updating the npm version several times.
I tried changing the fields in Firestore database.

Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? and Formatting text and code

I am so sorry about that.

Thanks for the update. Please update again to show how you import FieldValue. In general, please read how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example and https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example - as following that guidance makes it much more likely we can help efficiently.

import { FieldValue } from 'firebase/firestore';
This is how I import FieldValue.
